# Inline javascript to avoid hackish data APIs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jqplot, jinja2

I need to render a plot using jqplot from within a jinja2 template.  The template has access to the data that needs to be plotted.  I could pass the data to some external javascript by embedding it in the html or via some API, but it seems more practical and less hack-ish to simply include a few lines of javascript to render the plot within the template.  That way everything involved in plotting is grouped together.

Is there some standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking beyond the obvious.  The standard way of embedding data directly into a page is to just declare the javascript data structure inside `<script>` tags right in the page HTML.  Then you can just directly refer to the data with your other page javascript without having to fetch the data from a server:

```
<script>
var pageData = [
   {prop1: true, prop2: false, name: "foo"},
   {prop1: false, prop2: false, name: "whatever"},
];
</script>
```

or, if you want to namespace the global to you have a single place to put other globals:

```
<script>
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.pageData = [
   {prop1: true, prop2: false, name: "foo"},
   {prop1: false, prop2: false, name: "whatever"},
];
</script>
```

If your question is about something different than this, please clarify.

Comment: So, why not simply include the jqplot functions to render the plot within the inline script tags?

Comment: @astex - you're free to do that too.  If you have javascript that is used on multiple pages, it is generally better if it is in an external JS file so that browser can more effectively load it from cache as the viewer goes between pages.  If it's only used on one page, then you can certainly put it inline if you want.

Comment: I was confounded by the vast number of threads on sf that recommend avoiding inline javascript completely.

Comment: Avoid inline scripts for repeated code (used on multiple pages) for cache efficiency, but there's no problem using it for one-off code or for page-specific data.